# Iterate variables in Con statement in Raster Calculator- model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, iterator, con

I have this formula which works fine in raster calculator on its own. Here is a simplified version of it:

Con((("Trial_analysis\winter_pm" == 2)) & ("Wind_directions\winter_pm_WD" <=b) & ("Wind_directions\winter_pm_WD" >= c) ,d)

I need however to iterate through the variables `(b,c,d)`, I have tables for all these variables. Basically I need the model to go through the winter_pm raster, iterate through all the conditions, and generate rasters from the list of values 'd'. So for every  b and c that are true, generate a raster with value d (of course limited to the cells where those conditions are true). 
I tried implementing many variations in model builder using iterate value fields then calculate values for the tables a,b,c,d. But when I use these as inline variables in the raster calculator condition statement only ONE raster is generated. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just chain 3 functions in your model? Have each function create one of the rasters you want.  To my knowledge there isn't a way to make a Con tool create multiple outputs.